# Trouble with animation in non-chrome browsers

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have some jQuery that is successfully adding the needed class for the animation below.

1) First, the animation below is only playing in Chrome. My IE (version 11.0) and Firefox (32.0.3) are not playing the animation at all.

2) Second, if I don't have 'opacity: 1;' in my animation class, the element will fade back to opacity 0 (its original value). Is there a better way to have it stay at the final value of an animation without having to set it in the animation? Seems kind of non-intuitive to be setting properties of the element in the animation class, as it's not clear when it takes effect (before, after the keyframe).

HTML:

```
<!-- Appear after 1 second -->
<h1 data-appear='1'>1</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    opacity: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes appear {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  50%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes appear {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  50%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes appear {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  50%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes appear {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  50%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

.appear.delay1 {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -o-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;

    animation: appear;
    -o-animation-name: appear;
    -moz-animation-name: appear;
    -webkit-animation-name: appear;

    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) The secret lies within the order of the CSS rules. You have not defined an animation yet when you define the duration. If I switch the order it works for me in the latest firefox:

```
.appear.delay1{

    animation: appear;
    -o-animation: appear;
    -moz-animation: appear;
    -webkit-animation: appear;

    animation-duration: 1s;
    -o-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

2.) You don't need to define opacity if you define the fill mode. With fill mode you can specify what state of the animation will stick when the animation is complete. In this case you want 100% to stick, so you should set the fill mode to forwards.

```
-o-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

I pieced it all together in the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mxa377m4/

Comment: Does the order of the browsers also matter? I notice people tend to place the most basic statement (in your case, 'animation-fill-mode') at the bottom of the list of browser supports.

Comment: I suppose it does not really matter. I do believe the latest supported statement is the one that is applied to the element. So for example: if the latest chrome supports both `-webkit` and the non-prefixed one. It will use the bottom-most statement. Which is `animation-fill-mode` in the code above. If all statements are equal it shouldn't really matter. If the vendor implementation is different than the unprefixed W3C one, then it does.

Comment: So it's akin to declaring and setting the width of an element 5 times over, with different values each time... the latest one will be used. So if the browser supports multiple prefixes, they're all equal to it, meaning the latest one will take precedence. I know they say to avoid "Thanks" comments, but whatever - thanks for the quick results and great insight.

Comment: Exactly. I created a fiddle where I moved the unprefixed `animation-duration` below the `-moz` one. I left the `-moz` at 1s and set the unprefixed to 5s. You'll see that Firefox takes 5s to animate. http://jsfiddle.net/mxa377m4/1/. Glad I could help ;)

Comment: -- Don't forget to press 'Run' to fix caching problems.